# error de conexion sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, mssql, sqlsrv

Por que este código no conecta desde mi hosting a un VPS remoto? ya abrí el puerto 1433 y si me permite conectarme vía mssql_connect pero quiero subir de php 5.3 a 7.0 el problema que al crear el script como me aparece en el tutorial minuto 13:06

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8l8CV0YmTM][1]

el siguiente código php no conecta a mi server y en administrador 7.0 active **sqlsrv** y **pdo_sqlsrv**

```
<?php
$serverName = "144.2.255.66";
$connectionInfo = array( "DataBase"=>"playsdb","UID"=>"sqluser","PWD"=>"sqlpass","CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn_sis = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if(!$conn_sis){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 CharName FROM chars ORDER BY Row ASC";
$execut = sqlsrv_query ($conn_sis,$sql);
$muestra = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($execut);
Echo "El usuario es:". $muestra['CharName'];?>
```

Obtengo este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /home/createso/storagebackups.createsoftw.com/2.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/createso/storagebackups.createsoftw.com/2.php on line 4
```

y si utilizo el siguiente tipo de conexión si me da **OK** (En español significa CONECTA):

```
$conn_sis = mssql_connect( $ip, $user, $pass) or die ('no conecto');
```

pasa que leí por hay que debo usar PDO combinarlos con **sqlsrv** u **odbc** para hacer las INSERT TABLES mas seguras y UPDATE Tables mas seguras. entonces necesito aprender a configurar mis servers. por ello ando pidiendo ayuda para poder estudiar como llamar y ver ejecutar modificar etc bases de datos sql server. para evitar las variables NO DESEADAS. (dañinas) y me parece buena opción sqlsrv o odbc

¿Cuál seria la mas recomendada? OJO no y no quiero ni debo guardar el sitio web php en en servidor dedicado u vps en donde este alojado e instalado el SQL server.

Comment: ¿Qué controlador quieres usar exactamente?

Comment: 7.0 active sqlsrv y pdo_sqlsrv arriba lo puse amigo

Comment: eso en el hosting es el version de php

Comment: http://storagebackups.createsoftw.com/info.php

Comment: ¿Dónde dice que está activado uno de **esos dos controladores**? Y, pregunto de nuevo, ¿cuál **de los dos controladores** piensas usar? `sqlsrv` es un controlador y `pdo_sqlsrv` es otro controlador... Sea el que sea que decidas usar, debe estar instalado en el servidor. De hecho, el error de *undefined function* ocurre **cuando el controlador no está instalado o no está activado**. Tienes que decidirte por uno y seguir las instrucciones para instalarlo y activarlo.

Comment: Como complemento, en el manual de PHP: [mssql_connect](http://phpweb.hostnet.com.br/manual/es/function.mssql-connect.php) Advertencia, Esta función está OBSOLETA en PHP 7.0.0. Usar: PDO::__construct(), sqlsrv_connect() o odbc_connect().

Comment: Perdon amigo que indica la pregunta? no dice de casualidad que en uno da OK? que en cual tengo el problema? y cuando usted dice contrador en los HOSTING hay un selector de PHP (Controlador de EXTENCIONES) y si si estan activados e instalados. claramente indico arriba que MSSQL_CONNECT no es el del problema lea con atencion la pregunta de nuevo amigo

Comment: Conchale amigo perdona no habia entendido tu pregunta no se es que ambos estan instalados "segun" el panel y el archivo info.php me dice que esta instalado y que no. sierto? lo que me interesa es que conecte y yo pueda haer consultas la base de datos. OJO si o si guardando siempre en hosting los archivos php ya que no uso xampp..

Comment: Hola hermano buen dia, puse mejor la pregunta al correjir errores ortograficos

Comment: Quiero usar es **pdo_sqlsrv**  y creo que si esta instalado

Comment: La forma de conectarse con `pdo_sqlsrv` es usando `new PDO` como muestran la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15), así como el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php). Revisa los ejemplos allí y actualiza tu código. Ningunas de las formas de conectar en el actual código es para `pdo_sqlsrv`, por eso precisamente te preguntaba qué controlador ibas a usar. Además, asegúrate que ese controlador está debidamente instalado, sin suponer nada.

Comment: bro por que no lo comentas asi te califico y haces una muestra? e gustaria ya que estoy iniciando en ese lenguaje